# Get a reference to a component of current route in Angular 2's router?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a clean way to get a reference to the component of current route?

This seems to work, but seems very hacky:

```
 this.router.currentInstruction.
  component.componentType.prototype.somePropertyOrFunction();
```

Comment: From where do you want to have this hint?

Comment: Main component,where I setup my routes

Comment: I think that it's the way to get it but you can remove the `prototype` level to call a method on it ;-)

Comment: well actually the 'ComponentType' is of type ComponentInstruction and it does not work if I simply remove the prototype

Comment: In fact, it's not the component instance but the component type. That's why you use the `prototype` but it's not actually the right instance. I added an answer describing this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, you don't have access to the component instance associated to the current route with your expression. You only get the component type. That's why you need to use the prototype but you get a reference to function and don't reference to methods of the component instance.

The main consequence will be that the `this` keyword (if used within the methods) will be undefined.

To access the component instance associated to the current route, you could leverage the `OnActivate` hook interface to set this instance into a shared service when the route is activated:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-cmp',
  template: `
    <div>routerOnActivate: {{log}}</div>
  `})
  export class SomeCmp implements OnActivate {
    constructor(private service:RouteStateService) {
    }

    routerOnActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
      this.service.setCurrentRouteComponent(this);
    }
 }
```

Then you would be able to access the component instance this way:

```
var component = this.service.getCurrentRouteComponent();
```

Comment: interesting, why there is no reference to component instance in activatedRoute, sometimes it is quite handy to have it there

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to access the component instance using `RouterOutletMap` that is a kind of stateful service used by Angular to store instances rendered by `router-outlet` directive. You might need these types:

```
import { Router, RouterOutletMap, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
```

Top-level `outletMap` is a property of the `router`, but it's not visible in TS so you might need cast to `any`:

```
constructor(private router:Router) {
    const rootOutletMap:RouterOutletMap = (<any>this.router).outletMap;
}
```

The `RouterOutletMap` is a javascript object that has a property `_outlets`. This `_outlets` is a hash-map-object containing `RouterOutlet` instances by the outlet name. If an outlet has no name, it will be 'primary'. After you got `RouterOutlet` you can grab the component instance:

```
const rootOutletMap:RouterOutletMap = (<any>this.router).outletMap,
      outletsHash = (<any>rootOutletMap)._outlets,
      primaryOutlet:RouteOutlet = outletsHash['primary'], // 'primary' is the default name

      component = primaryOutlet.component; // <-- this is the instance
```

`RouterOutletMap` is a tree, so the root map has a reference to children and so on. You can organize a lookup procedure to find a component for a particular route if you need to. Here is an example of recursive components extraction:

```
// returns an array of all the router-outlets component currently rendered
private getComponentsChain(routerOutletMap: RouterOutletMap) {
    const outlets: any = (<any>routerOutletMap)._outlets,
          outletsList = [],
          components = [];

    _.forOwn(outlets, (value: RouterOutlet, key: string) => {
        outletsList.push(value);
        components.push(value.component);
    });

    const recursiveComponents = _.flatMap(
        outletsList,
        (o: RouterOutlet) => this.getComponentsChain(o.outletMap));

    return [...components, ...recursiveComponents];
}

/* ...then somewhere in component: */
console.log(this.getComponentsChain((<any>this.router).outletMap));
```

Few points to note if you go this way:

- it uses non-public angular features so that might change in the future;
- router outlets have it's own lyfecycle, you might get 'Outlet is not activated' error if you pick it at the wrong moment.

Answer (score 1):

Only short (but hacky) way I found is next (Angular 4, 6, 7, 8):

```
const currentComponent = (router as any).rootContexts.contexts 
  && (router as any).rootContexts.contexts.get('primary')
  && (router as any).rootContexts.contexts.get('primary').outlet.component;
```

BEWARE: that's a HACK, may not work if you have more than one router outlet etc.

Answer (score -3):

You can get the type of the component from a CanActivate guard. For example:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class MyGuard: CanActivate
    {
      canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) : boolean{
         let componentType = route.routeConfig.component;
      }
    }
```