# Angular2 open dialog from service

Tags: angular

I have a service that manage http connections (essentially to put the correct headers on the post function). I want it to manage errors when I receive a message.

Everything works very well, but I face a rather important issue : when the message I receive is indicating an error, how can I open a dialog from this service ?

A possibility would be to get the current component (associated with the route) and then "attach" the dialog to it. But I don't succeed in both parts.

For the first one, i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36201093/7343478), but seems complicated and dirty in my case.

Comment: Put the dialog in your app.component, create a rxjs `subject` to tracks errors in your service, let your app.component subscribe to the rxjs `subject`. Trigger your subject with `subject.next()` to trigger errors.

Comment: It's working perfectly well. Perhaps add the comment as an answer to solve the post.

Comment: You could also isolate this by creating an error-viewer component and use that in your app component.